# Using Green's theorem: Area of Descartes' folium

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to calculate the area of the loop in the folium of Descartes using Green's theorem. The loop can be parameterized $x = \frac{3at}{1+t^3}$, $y=\frac{3at^2}{1+t^3}$, $0\leq t < \infty$.

$$\iint_F 1=\int_{\partial F}x\,dy=\int_{0}^\infty \left(\frac{3at}{1+t^3}\right)\left(\frac{6at(1+t^3)-3t^2(3at^2)}{(1+t^3)^2}dt\right)$$

$$=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{18a^2t^2 (1+t^3)-27a^2t^5}{(1+t^3)^3}=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{9a^2t^2(2(1+t^3)-3t^3)}{(1+t^3)^3},$$and the book tells me the answer is $$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^2}{(1+t^3)^2}.$$ Where is my error?

Comment: I wonder who downvoted the question, this is clearly not a problem statement question. +1

Comment: @Eric Auld: The area obviously depends on $a$, so something is awry with your book's purported answer. (That's not to say your answer is right, but in a quick skim I don't see anything wrong with your calculations....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Green's theorem is:
$$
\int_F\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)dxdy = \oint_{\partial F} (L  dx + M dy).
$$
The textbook uses one possible choice for the differential form $\omega = (L  dx + M dy)$:
$$
\int_F 1\,dxdy = \frac12 \oint_{\partial F} (\color{blue}{-ydx} + x dy),\tag{1}
$$
not just $x\,dy$, you need that extra blue term to get to what is similar to your book's answer. Now plugging the parametrization gives
$$
\frac12 \int^{\infty}_0 \left(-\frac{3at^2}{1+t^3}\Big(\frac{3at}{1+t^3}\Big)' + \frac{3at}{1+t^3}\Big(\frac{3at^2}{1+t^3}\Big)' \right)dt.
$$

**Some updates:**
Formula (1) simplifies to
$$
\frac12 \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{9a^2t^2}{(1+t^3)^2}dt, \tag{2}
$$
which is what you have in your book. If we use yours 
$$
\int_F 1\,dxdy =  \oint_{\partial F} xdy = \int_{0}^\infty\frac{9a^2t^2(2 -t^3)}{(1+t^3)^3}dt,
$$
above formula will yield the same value with (2). Similarly, choosing $-ydx$ will give you same value as well:
$$
\int_F 1\,dxdy =  \oint_{\partial F} -ydx = \int_{0}^\infty\frac{9a^2t^2(2t^3 -1)}{(1+t^3)^3}dt.
$$
The choice is sure not unique. Furthermore, w/o computing the value of above three integrals, you could always prove:
$$
 \oint_{\partial F} -ydx = \oint_{\partial F} xdy
$$
through integration by parts. Reason why choosing $\omega = -ydx + x dy$ is probably like you said, leading to a more manageable formula.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I am applying the operator $d$ to differential forms incorrectly. Green says $\int_{\partial D}\omega = \int_{D}d\omega$. If $\omega = x\,dy + 0\,dx$,  isn't $d\omega = d(x)dy = (1\,dx + 0\,dy)dy=1\,dx\,dy$?

Comment: @EricAuld Your formula is perfectly right. Finally, the values are the same.

Comment: Oh, I see. The $y\,dx - x\,dy$ just leads to a more manageable formula in this case!

Comment: @EricAuld I updated some more into the answer, see if you are okay with it.