# Calculating area of the loop in Folium of Descartes

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, area, curves

The curve is given as a function of a parameter $t$ as follows $$x=\frac{3at}{1+t^3}~;~y=\frac{3at^2}{1+t^3}$$ Now I am supposed to use the following formula specifically used for calculating areas enclosed by closed curves: $$\int_{t_{1}}^{t_2}\left[x(t)y'(t)-y(t)x'(t)\right]dt$$ where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are values of $t$ where the curve intersects itself. Those values should be found by setting $$\frac{3at_1}{1+t_1^3}=\frac{3at_2}{1+t_2^3}$$ and $$\frac{3at_1^2}{1+t_1^3}=\frac{3at_2^3}{1+t_2^3}$$ and then solve the system. However I am unable to do this since the system is not linear. How to proceed?

Edit: I think that this is not a [duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447438/using-greens-theorem-area-of-descartes-folium) since the approach is different (no use of Green's theorem).

Comment: more or less duplicate of (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/447438)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Green's theorem: Area of Descartes' folium](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447438/using-greens-theorem-area-of-descartes-folium)

Comment: The first answer was incorrect and I have provided a correct one below.

Comment: You should not leave a check mark on an incorrect solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer I accepted is sufficient and the solution provided checks out with the one in my textbook. Your answer is given by using complex analysis which is out of my scope currently. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: Aha, I finally see what the problem is. The equation you said to use for the area of a closed curve $$\int_{t_{1}}^{t_2}\left[x(t)y'(t)-y(t)x'(t)\right]dt$$ is incorrect. It should be $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{t_{1}}^{t_2}\left[x(t)y'(t)-y(t)x'(t)\right]dt$$ If you don't believe me, take it up with your teacher, or better yet, try it on some simple problem like the area of a circle, $x=\cos\theta,\ y=r\sin\theta$. Your equation will give $A=2\pi r^2$. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a drawing of the curve, and this is what you get

[image]

The curve crosses itself at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ which can only happen in two cases

$$
t= 0 ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ t\to +\infty
$$

The are is then

$$
A = \int_0^{+\infty}{\rm d}t~\left(x\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} - y\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t}\right) = 9a^2 \int_0^{+\infty}{\rm d}t \frac{t^2}{(1 + t^3)^3} = 3a^2
$$

Comment: Thank you! I thought that I shouldn't end up with an improper integral because we avoided those while studying areas under curves. Anyways, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with the previous solution. Anyone can tell from looking at the plot that the area is not equal to 3. I approached this in a different way, namely in the complex plane, where the area $A$ is given by

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int \Im\{z^*\dot z\}dt$$

Thus,

$$z=3a\frac{t+it^2}{1+t^3}\\
z^*=3a\frac{t-it^2}{1+t^3}\\
\dot z=3a\frac{1-2t^3+i(2t-t^4)}{1+t^3}\\
\Im\{ z^*\dot z\}=9a^2\frac{t^2}{(1+t^3)^2}
$$

And finally,

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \Im\{z^*\dot z\}dt=9a^2\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{3a^2}{2}$$

I have verified this result numerically.

Comment: Can you tell me how to find area between this curve and it's asymptote.